# get heading name as url using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="myclass selected">
    <h2 class = "title">#Content 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
    <h2 class = "title">#Content 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
    <h2 class = "title">#Content 3</h2>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
    <h2 class = "title">#Content 4</h2>
</div>
```

I want to show as "http://example.com/#content-1" in url and want to update for each selection. Is this possible to do that using jquery ?

Comment: do you want to click at #Content 1 and change url?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please provide more information.

Comment: I have no idea what you want.

Comment: i want to change the url when i click using the next click funtion.

Comment: I believe that you want anchors instead of h2

Comment: $('.selected').show();$(".next").click(function(){ i am using this function. i want to change the url when i select the next one

Comment: @user1621335 What is `.next`? There is no element with class of `next` in your markup!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.myclass h2').click(function(){
    window.location = 'http://example.com/' + $.text(this).toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
});
```

---

Is there any reason you're not using regular links? Try this:

```
<div class="myclass selected">
    <h2 class="title">
        <a href="#content-1">#Content 1</a>
    </h2>
</div>
<!-- Add the others here... -->
```

Then, just add this script:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    hash && $('.myclass').removeClass('selected').filter(function(){
        return $(this).find('a').prop('href') == hash;
    }).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: We can also use `window.location.hash`.

Comment: @undefined - The OP has not specified that they're currently on `http://example.com/`.

Comment: In this code, when i refresh the page it starts from initial. Is this possible to get the same content which is on the url even i refresh the page ?

Comment: @user1621335 - I'm *truly* sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: if this is my link "http://example.com/#content-3". when i refresh my page, it doesn't show the content 3. instead of that it show the content 1. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @user1621335 - I hope I understood you correctly. Check out the code I just added.

Comment: Please go to here http://jsfiddle.net/sureshmonster/Jqfsn/ i just want to get url what i have in h2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 var selected = $('.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    selected.hide();

    var next = selected.next(".myclass");
```

to

```
 var selected = $('.selected');
 var next = selected.next(".myclass");
 selected.removeClass('selected');
 selected.hide();
```

You are removing the class `selected` before assigning it to `next`..

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/Jqfsn/1/